# CoreNLP Road Map

Tags: stanford-nlp

The road map for CoreNLP is unclear.  Is it in maintenance mode? I'm happy to see emphasis on StanfordNLP, but the lack of visibility into the direction is concerning. If the new neural models are better, will wee see them wrapped in the Java CoreNLP API's?

Comment: 'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking about future plans or release dates are not programming questions. Contact the project directly for information about their roadmap. If you have code-related questions about using the libraries, they're welcome here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreNLP is not yet in maintenance mode. We are going to put in some quite significant (and compatibility-breaking) changes over the summer. Among other things, we're going to convert across to using UDv2 (from the current UDv1), we're going to make tokenization changes to English and perhaps other languages to better align with UD and "new" (since about 2004!) Penn Treebank tokenization, and we'll have more consistent availability and use of word vectors. These changes should increase compatibility between the Java and Python packages, and over time also make it possible for us to use more data to train Python stanfordnlp models. Now that the Python stanfordnlp v0.2 is out, work on CoreNLP should pick up.

On the other hand, most of the research energy in the Stanford NLP group has now moved to exploring neural models built in Python on top of the major deep learning frameworks. (Hopefully that's not a surprise to hear!) It is therefore less likely that major new components will be added to CoreNLP. It's hard to predict the future, but it is reasonable to expect that CoreNLP will head more in the direction of being a stable, efficient-on-CPU NLP package, rather than something implementing the latest neural models.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. The primary concern is that the new PyTorch based models will surpass those available in CoreNLP, and those of us who've built large Java code bases will have no way to easily access the PyTorch models. For example, we want to use the state of the art solutions for PoS, DepParse, CoRef. It seems like we would need a JNI style interface to these models, as HTTP wrappers would likely be too slow. Or am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: No promises...but we have interest in building a Python server like the Java server, and if it's not too big of an effort one could run a Java pipeline and submit requests to a Python server in the background running the neural models...not sure about the throughput of such a set up, but I would've thought the processing time of dependency parsing or coref would dwarf the communication time between server and client

Comment: In fact, there are already some prototypes allowing a Java pipeline to access an external server floating around in our internal repo...

Comment: You might be right about the overhead of http being too small to worry about. If you move the prototype code to an external repo, perhaps we could contribute. The beauty of open source... and thanks for the answers.